# How to use Vue's FunnelGraph.js with Python's Flask

Tags: vue.js, flask

I am new to both Vue and Python Flask. I have been searching for some charts that Vue provides. One of them is the FunnelGraph.js. I am however not quite sure how to integrate them together.

I tried to follow the documentation `https://github.com/greghub/funnel-graph-js#usage` but I'm not quite sure where to use the `graph` variable. I have chosen to use its CDN.

In python's Flask's `app.py` I have,

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

In the `about.html`, I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/funnel-graph-js@1.3.9/dist/css/main.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/funnel-graph-js@1.3.9/dist/css/theme.min.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="graph">
      <h1>graph</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/funnel-graph-js@1.3.9/dist/js/funnel-graph.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      var graph = new FunnelGraph({
          container: '.funnel',
          gradientDirection: 'horizontal',
          data: [12000, 5700, 360],
          displayPercent: true,
          direction: 'horizontal'
      });

      graph.draw();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the current setup I get the error from the chrome inspector console:

```
funnel-graph.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
    at funnel-graph.min.js:1
    at g (funnel-graph.min.js:1)
    at e.value (funnel-graph.min.js:1)
    at new e (funnel-graph.min.js:1)
    at about:21
```

Comment: This is the same plugin for `vue.js` [vue-funnel-graph-js](https://github.com/greghub/vue-funnel-graph-js)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with FunnelGraph: it appears to throw this error when you define `data` as an array, although they have this example in their documentation. To work around it, define your data as an object:

```
var graph = new FunnelGraph({
    container: '#graph',
    gradientDirection: 'horizontal',
    displayPercent: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    data: {
        values: [12000, 5700, 360]
    },
});

graph.draw();
```

I also had to adjust your container selector to be `#graph` since that is what you have in the markup.

Comment: Did it work for you such that you can see the whole funnel graph? I seem to only be able to see a couple lines and a couple percentage numbers. But your solution definitely fixed the inspector error.